# running vlc whitout it appearing in taskbar kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, vlc, taskbar

I'm trying to get a fancy background by playing a movie on my desktop.
My current command that runs at startup is

```
tmux new -n background-movie -d  kstart --alldesktops cvlc --quiet --daemon --no-stats --video-wallpaper --loop --no-audio --no-video-title ~/Videos/Background.wmv
```

It works perfect, except that there's an entry for vlc in my taskbar which isn't doing anything.
Is there a way to stop this movie from appearing as an instance of vlc without altering the behaviour of vlc in any way so I can watch movies normally with vlc?

Answer (score 0):

Just open VLC, press the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + P to open "Preferences", in "Interface Settings", inside the box "Look and feel", uncheck "Show systray icon". Restart VLC to check. Voila! :D

Comment: yeah, but the next time I try to watch a movie I don't have a systray icon. Which is quite annoying when you're running a program.
I want it for only the background movie instance to not appear.

Comment: I guess you should edit your question to reflect that requirement... Just to make sure others will better understand your problem and will offer a better answer.